# Can't use <xsl:evaluate> in Saxon 9.7

Tags: saxon, xslt-3.0

I'm running the XML Maven Plugin with this POM fragment:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>transform</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <transformationSets>
                    <transformationSet>
                        <dir>${basedir}/target/xml</dir>
                        <stylesheet>${basedir}/target/typesetting/fop/xslt/PhotoBook-fo.xslt</stylesheet>
                    </transformationSet>
                </transformationSets>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
                    <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
                    <version>9.7.0-15</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The stylesheet contains a feature, `<xsl:evaluate>`, that is part of XSLT 3.0, which I understand is supported in Saxon-HE 9.7.0. The stylesheet correctly declares the XSLT version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
            xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

But processing this fragment:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="xhtml:tr[1]/xhtml:td">
            <xsl:element name="table-column" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
                <xsl:attribute name="column-width">
                    <xsl:evaluate select="@width"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

I get

```
[INFO] --- xml-maven-plugin:1.0.1:transform (default) @ birds-portfolio-1 ---
Static error at xsl:evaluate on line 132 column 56 of xhtml5-fo.xslt:  
XTSE0010: Unknown XSLT element: evaluate
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saxon 9.7 HE does not support any XSLT 3.0 language feature, you need PE or EE for that (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/xsl-elements/evaluate.html). The only enhancement you get in 9.7 HE with `version="3.0"` stylesheets is access to XPath 3.0 expressions (like `let`) and functions (like `serialize` or `parse-xml`).

As for your code, are you sure you need `xsl:evaluate`? It seems

```
            <xsl:attribute name="column-width" select="@width"/>
```

might suffice, unless your `width` attribute contains an XPath expression you need to evaluate.

I would even replace

```
    <xsl:for-each select="xhtml:tr[1]/xhtml:td">
        <xsl:element name="table-column" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <xsl:attribute name="column-width">
                <xsl:evaluate select="@width"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

with

```
    <xsl:for-each select="xhtml:tr[1]/xhtml:td">
        <table-column xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" column-width="{@width}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks, I got lost in the various editions. Yes, I do need evaluation, because I might pass an expression using some variables involving page measurements (the stuff is related to FOP for typesetting books). I also need to do lots of refactorings to my XSLT code, but at the moment I'm stuck with the need of evaluate, and I have to work on it before improving the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Martin Honnen already helpfully pointed out (+1) that Saxon 9.7 HE doesn't support XSLT 3.0, but I wanted to add another possibility for future readers who may have problems in this area:  If Saxon 9.7 EE or PE fails to find a proper **license key**, it appears to continue to work with reduced functionality, perhaps as it would under HE.

On the one hand, this sort of  graceful degradation can be helpful, but on the other hand, it can also be confusing to licensed EE or PE users who don't expect this behavior when failing to properly place a license key file on a new machine setup.